# checked={false} changing a controlled input of type checkbox to be uncontroled input

Tags: reactjs, input, checkbox

The following code returns the error: A component is changing a controlled input of type checkbox to be uncontrolled.

```
function CheckBox(props) {
    const id = props.id;
    const onChange = props.onChange;
    const flag = props.flag;
    const lock = props.lock;

    if (lock === true) {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <input className="tgl tgl-skewed" id={id} type="checkbox" onChange={onChange} />
                <label className="tgl-btn" data-tg-off={flag + " is OFF"} data-tg-on={flag + " is ON"} htmlFor={id}></label>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <input className="tgl tgl-skewed" id={id} type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked={false} value={false}/>
                <label className="tgl-btn" data-tg-off={flag + " is OFF"} htmlFor={id}></label>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

The error disappears when I remove `checked={false}` but I need it...

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

When you have an `onChange`, you cannot have a fixed value. Usually `onChange` will update a state, and that state will be used as `value`

`onChange` means that you to manage the value yourself, so a state (or props) value is expected

Comment: that's interesting and logical. sadly my error is still here after this correction. I just corrected my post thanks to your answer. is it the same story with 'checked={false} value={false}' ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that your input was a checkbox. For checkbox, the checked parameter must be a state (or props)

Comment: yeah but this checkbox is wrapped inside a 'if else' and if the condition is 'false' i want that my checkbox is OFF and disabled . i have different CSS rules for the two state. that's why i need to use 'checked={false} ' inside my 'else'

Comment: Then try: `checked={props.lock}`